# NodeJS child_process.execFile() always return Unknown system errno 193

Tags: node.js

Simply, i can't use the child_process.execFile(). It always contain error in callback.

**child.js**

```
console.log('I\'m child');
```

**main.js**

```
var cp = require('child_process');

cp.execFile('./child.js', function (err, stdout,stderr) {
    console.log('Err: ',err);
    console.log('STDerr: ',stderr);
});
```

The error object in the callback is

```
{ [Error: spawn Unknown system errno 193]
  code: 'Unknown system errno 193',
  errno: 'Unknown system errno 193',
  syscall: 'spawn' }
```

Comment: What are the first couple lines of child.js?

Comment: There is only one line in child.js

Comment: What OS do you use? I tried you code in Windows and I see the same

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows 7. Should I try on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that child.js is not a valid executable program.  If you are on Linux or Mac you can fix that by writing this at the very top of child.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

You will then need to say `chmod +x child.js` to make the file executable.  The line is called a "shebang line" and it tells the system what interpreter to use to run the rest of the file.  You'll need to have node in your $PATH for it to work.

If you don't like that, or are not using a Unix-like system, you can do this:

```
cp.execFile('/some/path/to/node', ['./child.js'])
```

The first argument must be the full path to your node interpreter program (perhaps node.exe on Windows, I don't know if that matters).

Finally, none of this really makes that much sense if you don't really need to launch a second node interpreter process.  You can try including one file in the other--some ideas for that are here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: @Green: Fixed, Node wants `args` to be an array.  Not sure if that changed since I wrote the answer 1.5 years ago, but anyway please try the updated version.